# Binding a button in WPF using PRISM DelegateCommand

Tags: wpf, prism

I am just starting to learn WPF using the PRISM library. Please help me to solve one question. How to bind a button using DelegateCommand?
In the code behind everything is fine. In the MVVM code I can't get it to work.

Thanks.

My code in XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Panel.Modules.DockingManager.DockingManagerPanel.DockingManagerPanelPrism"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">

        <Grid>
                <Button x:Name="button"
                    Command="{Binding LoadAllFiles}"
                    CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=textBox}"
                    Height="24" Width="24">
                </Button>
                
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox" </TextBox>
        </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

And my code in ViewModel:

```
public class DockingManagerPanelViewModel : BindableBase
    {

        public DelegateCommand LoadAllFiles { get; set; }

        public DockingManagerPanelViewModel()
        {
            LoadAllFiles = new DelegateCommand(LoadTxt);
        }
        private void LoadTxt()
        {
            var dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            dialog.Multiselect = true;
            dialog.FileName = "Document";
            dialog.DefaultExt = ".txt";
            dialog.Filter = "Text documents (*.*)|*.*";

            bool? result = dialog.ShowDialog();

            if (result == true)
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(dialog.FileName));
                sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's `CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=textBox}"` supposed to do?

Comment: If you remove that commandtarget line, what happens? Do you get to a breakpoint in loadtxt?  You don't do anything with your stream, so that's going nowhere.   Was that intentional? Something else to think about is why this is a command at all though. You're showing an openfiledialog which is ui. This is arguably all view responsibility you're doing here and a click handler doesn't seem like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @Andy I did not fully describe the question, for which I apologize. In this code I am trying to pass the contents of a file to a TextBox. When I put a breakpoint in the LoadTxt method everything works even without the CommandTarget line. The Openfiledialog works correctly. But when I select a file nothing happens, the file doesn't pass its contents to the TextBox. Why am I not using Click or ApplicationComands.Open? I would like in this code which I will add later, to win file loading speed and to control the file download myself.

Comment: @Haukinger Sorry. I was trying to pass the contents of a file to a TextBox.

Comment: You could read that file to a string using File.ReadAllText(). Bind a string property in your vm to the text property of your textbox. Set that string property.

Comment: @Haukinger OpenFileDialog works, but I can't transfer the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the text but not doing anything with what you read.  You need to read it into some sort of string property and then bind the `TextBox` to that property.

Also you are failing to use a `using` statement on the StreamReader.

The good news is that you don't need to use StreamReader.  You can just use the much simpler `File.ReadAllText` function.

First, add this to your view model.  A public property exposing the read text.  It uses `BindableBase`'s SetProperty to raise the proper event when the value changes

```
public string LoadedText
{
    get => _loadedText;
    set => SetProperty(ref _loadedText, value);
}

private string _loadedText = string.Empty;
```

Next, change the last few lines of your LoadTxt function to do this instead of using StreamReader

```
if (result == true)
    LoadedText = File.ReadAllText(dialog.FileName)
```

Finally, change the TextBox in XAML to look like this.  I made it one way becase I assume you do not want the user editing inside of it, to change the value in the backing `LoadedText` property.  A better approach might be to just use a `TextBlock` instead of a `TextBox`

```
  <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Text="{Binding LoadedText, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. Sorry for taking up your time. I would like to ask you a question. If this TextBox will be in another View.  How can I connect button which will be in ViewA and TextBox which will be in ViewB using PRISM library? I know how IEventAggregator works. Is there any other way? Or should I create another topic? Thanks again.

Comment: Depends on your application.  One approach is to pass the string via navigation.    `ViewA` might raise some `EventAggregator` event and put the string in the custom event class  that you write.  The Main Window could subscribe to the event and then Navigate to `View`B, passing the string along as one of the Navigation Parameters.  `ViewB` would need to implement `OnNavigatedTo`  Or, maybe you could put the string into some public property of some common, service that you create and register at Prims init time.   Both `ViewA` and and `ViewB` could receive the service via constructor injection.

Comment: I suggest watching the Prism training courses on PluralSight.  They're worth it.